# simple login implementation using php. (clearing a session so that hitting 'back' doesn't work when you logout)

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication, session-cookies

I've got a simple login system going with php sessions. The issue I'm having is even after hitting "logout", I can still go back to the previous page by hitting the back button.

The way I'm logging out is done by the following...

```
<?php
session_start(); 

session_unset();  
session_destroy();

header("Location: ./login.php"); // redirect to login page.

?>
```

How do I completely delete a session..?

Comment: Who says that the page you see when you hit back button isn't the cached one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will log you out. As commented, hitting back will more than likly be loading browser cache. Therefore as long as you have security properly in place - clicking on something should result in your login page being displayed.